# How can I load non-AMD dependencies in the defined order with dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd, legacy-code

I try to make a non-AMD library loadable with dojo, I've chosen a separate folder as a new (pseudo) AMD-package and placed the files of that library in that folder, together with the `main.js` file, which will get loaded by convention by the dojo loader when the package is requested. In this main.js file I simply put the names of my library files in the dependency list of the `define()` call.

```
define([
    "jquery", 
    "./lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min",
    "./the.actual.library.that.uses.the.others",
], function () {
    return window.someGlobalSetByTheLibrary;
});
```

The problem with this is: **the loading** order of that dependencies depends on the network latency, **it is not guaranteed to be the order they appear in the `define()`.**

That causes (sometimes) an error because the actual library file needs its own dependencies to be loaded first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dojo has a perfect means to help yourself: [loader plugins](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd#plugins).

You can write your own sequential loading plugin that ensures the loading order for you.

(For copyright reasons of corporate owned code I can not post the implementation here, but it's quite easy using dojo's `Deferred` and `Promise` to chain one loading request after the other, internally using `require()` to do the actual loading).

Let's assume, your dojo loader plugin has the module id `myPackage/sequentialLoading`.
Then, your `main.js` will look like this.

```
define([
    "myPackage/sequentialLoading!jquery",
    "myPackage/sequentialLoading!./lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min",
    "myPackage/sequentialLoading!./the.actual.library.that.uses.the.others",
], function () {
    return window.someGlobalSetByTheLibrary;
});
```

Comment: Make sure you implement the `normalize` method in your loader and return an absolute module id with a unique postfix (which you later remove again in the `load` method.)
That way, you prevent caching and ensure that you get a call to load() for each of your sequential references, even if some of them occur multiple times (in different files).